# Can't setup AndEngine

Tags: java, eclipse, andengine

I use Android 4.2.2.
After i imported andengine from github and fixed the errors, i made my project.
After that i went to libraries, added the andengine, everything is ok.
http://s29.postimg.org/7dxzruh7b/ss1.png
I hit apply, go to the java build path to see if everything is ticked, and it is.
http://s8.postimg.org/lmudcwyg5/ss1.png

But, if I declare anything from andengine like, Camera camera, i can't import the andengine camera, because is not there.

If i open the properties again, I see that andengine is not added, is red, but 30 secs ago it was green.
http://s17.postimg.org/px8hdsagf/ss1.png

What should I do?

Please help me, I am very frustrated, i am trying to fix this from mounths, but I just can't..

If I copy the libs from the /bin folder from andengine and box2d my errors are gone, i can debug my app, but i get
01-05 16:42:07.550: E/AndEngine(2221): MainActivity.onCreateScene failed. @(Thread: 'GLThread 159')
01-05 16:42:07.550: E/AndEngine(2221): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/andengine/extension/physics/box2d/PhysicsWorld

And screen goes wierd.

Comment: please let me know if you try my solution, or if you need other further help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly found a way to make physics box 2d work.

I copied everything from /libs of andengine physicsbox2d to my /libs project folder.

[image]

Is sad that the winter break has just ended, and i figured out how to fix this..

Answer (score 1):

A have some andengine apps, and in all of them i do it like this:

- Build the andengine project, so you get a jar with all the classes inside. If the build is succesfull, you will find the jar in `{andengine_folder}/bin/andengine.jar`
- copy that jar, and put it in your project, in the `lib` folder
- Go to `Preferences > Android`, and remove andengine from the library section. (For the user that cannot find it, you have to scroll down, it is below the list of build targets)
- Go to `Preferences > Java Build Path > Libraries`

  - press `Add JARs`
  - in the project explorer that pops up, search for the andengine.jar file inside your project's lib folder, and add it.
- Clean and Build your project again, and everything should work like a charm

Comment: I already tried this, i can import everything, but If I add AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension and do the same, is not working.  I get- http://pastebin.com/GwVepc91 .

Comment: Please give me a contact adress like skype / facebook / mail or start a chat conversation

Comment: we can use stack overflow chat, i will look for you